# Get a custom attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm seeking a way to show a DIV(show-1, show-2,...) by selecting an OPTION which has a custom attribute show(1,2,...). Everything I tried didn't worked... :(

```
...
<select name="category" size="1">
   <option value="26" show="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="28" show="2">option 2</option>
   ...
</select>
...
<div id="show-1" style="visibility:hidden; height:0">...</div>
<div id="show-2" style="visibility:hidden; height:0">...</div>
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the code you've tried and what your goal is?

Comment: *"Everything I tried didn't worked..."* Examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest adding an `ID` for the `<select>`, and then depending on how many options you have in your dropdown, please reconsider [DRYing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it up a bit with regard to the hidden/visible toggling.

**HTML**

```
<select name="category" id="catselect" size="1">
   <option value="26" show="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="28" show="2">option 2</option>
</select>
<div id="show-1" style="visibility:hidden; height:0">111</div>
<div id="show-2" style="visibility:hidden; height:0">2222</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#catselect").change(function() {
    var f = $("#catselect :selected");
    if (f.attr("show") == "1") {
        $("#show-1").css("visibility","visible");
        $("#show-2").css("visibility","hidden");
    } else if (f.attr("show") == "2") {
        $("#show-2").css("visibility","visible");
        $("#show-1").css("visibility","hidden");
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KUDH/)

Comment: That works fine... Unfortunately all the other solutions didn't worked for my problem. Thanks

Comment: Is there also a way for accessing the #show-1 aso. without the if(f.attr("show") == "1") and instead by the value (show) selected  ... something like a loop or similar. Because there will now be about 100 shows. And typing in all the lines of jQuery one by one doesn't seem to be the perfect way... Thanks

Comment: Typing in all the lines, not to mention 100 shows, is not the best way to do it. That's why I suggested DRYing it up. Look into structuring your code in a generic manner that allows you to easily toggle without hardcoding the various options.

Answer (score 1):

Use data-show instead of show:

```
...
<select name="category" size="1">
   <option value="26" data-show="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="28" data-show="2">option 2</option>
   ...
</select>
...
<div id="show-1" style="visibility:hidden; height:0">...</div>
<div id="show-2" style="visibility:hidden; height:0">...</div>
...
```

Then you can access it like:

```
$('[name=category] option').click(function () {
    var show = $(this).attr('data-show');
});
```

or, if you prefer native javascript, there are two ways:

```
$('[name=category] option').click(function () {
    var show1 = this.getAttribute('data-show');
    var show2 = this.dataset.show;
});
```

Comment: would keyboard actions generate a `click` event on an `option` element?

Comment: Also note that `click` doesn't fire reliably on `option` elements.

Comment: No, it would only capture mouse clicks (or maybe touch events, I'm not 100%). For keyboard events you would want to do something like: $(window).on('keydown', function (e) { if (e.keyCode == [KEYCODE]) { /* do stuff */ } });

Comment: Yeah, realistically, you should be using <a> or <li> or something instead of <option>. And I've updated it to use attr() instead of data().

You may also want to attach the event to the <select> with on() with 'option' as the selector: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: *"No, it would only capture mouse clicks..."* On some browsers (I don't quite recall which), it doesn't even trigger when you click the option with the mouse. Sadly.

Comment: [`this.dataset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-dataset) is a nice idea, but doesn't work even in IE9 or IE10. IE11 is the first IE to support it.

Comment: Ahh, I've never really messed with attaching events to <option>s before. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your `show` attribute just like any other attribute, using `attr`. But using custom attributes without a `data-` prefix is a bad idea, so I'd suggest `data-show` instead.

Trigger your change using the `change` event on the `select`, and (if you want to be proactive on browsers where it works) the `click` event on the options`:

```
$("select[name=category]")
    .change(updateDivs)
    .find('option').click(updateDivs);
function updateDivs() {
    var select = $("select[name=category]"),
        val = select.val(),
        option = val && select.find("option[value=" + val + "]"),
        show = option && option.attr("data-show"); // or .attr("show") if you prefer to keep using it
    if (show) {
        $("div[id^=show-]").hide().filter("#show-" + show).show();
    }
}
```